# Creating an array of streamwriters

Tags: c#, arrays, streamwriter

Good, I need to have an array of streamwriters. Creating a few files from those and have the same text in each file.

I did some Googlin' but didn't came up with a solution..

The thing i was thinking of to create the arrays was the following

Any suggestions?

```
StreamWriter[] streamers;

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{

    streamers[i] = new StreamWriter(@"C:\stream");

}
```

Comment: That is almost correct! Hint: you should also allocate your `streamers` array.

Comment: Why do you need an array of `StreamWriter`?  Unless you're doing some sort of parallel programming, simply declare one `StreamWriter` and then use it multiple times sequentially.

Comment: This is one of the excercises in an assignment on streamwriters. Mostly those aren't usefull as you can see.

@Purrfection, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Interesting assignment. Don't forget to close each `StreamWriter` when you're done with it.

Comment: Declare your array first: `StreamWriter[] streamers = new StreamWriter[100];`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".